# Collecting multiple columns into comma,separated lists

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to transform a data frame in R according to this schema:

[image]

Note that the previously hot-encoded attribute Att_1 was collected as a comma-separated list in a single cell for IDy.

How can I do this in R (e.g. with the tidyr functions)?

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c("IDx", "IDy"), Att_1_1 = c(0,0), Att_1_2 = c(1,1), Att_1_3 = c(0, 1), Att_2 = c(1,1), Att_3 = c(1,0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you could do the following.

```
# set up new dataframe
res <- test[-(2:4)]

# add new varible
res$Att_1 <- apply(test[, 2:4], 1, function(x) c(names(test)[2:4][as.logical(x)]))
```

Here, `apply` loops through the rows of the subset data.frame and returns vectors of the names where the value of the row cell is equal to 1, using logical subsetting.

This returns

```
 res
  ID  Att_2 Att_3            Att_1
1 IDx     1     1          Att_1_2
2 IDy     1     0 Att_1_2, Att_1_3
```

Note that

```
res[["Att_1"]] <- ...
```

will also work.

Comment: One more question. I tried to alter the code by writing res[, "Att_1"] instead of res$Att_1, but it doesn't work. The apply command returns a list. What's the magic behind it? ;)

Comment: You can more or less get an idea from examining the code of `[<-.data.frame` and `$<-.data.frame`. The first is quite long and contains a number of checks as `[<-` must handle many more cases than `$<-`. About 3/4 of the way through, you will see the print out of the warning message, followed by the line `new.cols <- new.cols[seq_len(p)]`. I believe this truncates the list output from `apply` to include the first element. The code for `$<-` is much shorter and eventually uses `x[[name]] <- value` which I added in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive explanation. Btw. I substituted this line by an explicit paste with collapsing to join the elements into a comma-separated string, as they were otherwise just shown like this in the printout. Thanks for this awesome help. Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

As the OP requests `tidyr` functions, we `gather` the dataset into 'long' format, `filter` the rows where 'val' is 1, grouped by 'IDs', `paste` the 'key' column to create a `summarise`d column 'Att_1' and `left_join` by 'IDs' with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
   gather(key, val, Att_1_1:Att_1_3) %>%
   filter(val==1) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Att_1 = toString(key)) %>%
   left_join(df1[-(2:4)], ., by =  "ID") %>%
   select(ID, Att_1, Att_2, Att_3)
#   ID            Att_1 Att_2 Att_3
#1 IDx          Att_1_2     1     1
#2 IDy Att_1_2, Att_1_3     1     0
```

Comment: @Sotos  Thanks, I was coding based on the image showed by the OP.  Didnt see that the OP changed

Comment: Wow. Amazing! Thanks so much! But honestly, I really hoped for a more easy solution. I mean... the presented solution is really an art. And my true data frame is really, really huge and complex. PS: I edited the post to make the test data frame consistent with the picture, i.e. ID instead of IDs.

Comment: Maybe there is a more straightforward solution with non-tidyr functions!?

Comment: @CodingButStillAlive  It is only bcz u mentioned the `tidyr` approach in the post, othewise, there are more straightforward solution like lmo posted

Comment: I really appreciate your extra efforts. Nice to see how it would be done with tidyr. I was actually assuming that tidyr was a good starting point. But I was wrong ;)